# How to attach xsd file to xml in IDEA, when xsd locate not on this PC?

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, xsd

If we go on "Settings, languages & frameworks, schemas and DTDs" in IntelliJ IDEA we can chose location of xsd file. But if we take URL of file and put it into "Location", it become red and don't work, how we can show location of xsd if it locate not on this PC?

Comment: What URI do you use? Have you tried to add it using file chooser dialog?

Comment: @y.bedrov uri like http://example/product.xsd
Yes I try to use file chooser dialog, but here I can choose only xsd files on this pc.

Comment: Seems currently it's not possible. Feel  free to create feature request on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.